# Image is broken in full screen mode in Firefox by using angular-modal-service

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

While I am clicking on `full screen` button to see the image in full screen mode in Firefox then full image is not showing.Only some part of the image is showing. This is working fine in Chrome browser. Please find the below code and screenshot for broken image and actual image.

```
public initFullscreenModal = ():ng.IPromise<any> => this.ModalService
            .showModal({
                component: 'modalImageFullscreen',
                bodyClass: 'angular-modal-service-active',
                bindings: {
                    image: this.image
                },
                // This method is invoked when `ModalService.closeModals()` is called from within ModalService
                preClose: (modal: IDavis.Modal, result: any) => {
                    // We need this in order to properly close the Bootstrap modal via `.modal('hide')`
                    modal.element.modal('hide');
                }
            })
            .then( (modal: IDavis.Modal): void => {
                // required for Bootstrap Modal
                modal.element.modal('show');
            })
            .catch( (error: any) => {
               console.error('imageController.initModal().ModalService.showModal().ERROR', error);
            });
```

Reference Library : https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service#showmodal-options

[image: Broken Image]

[image: Actual Image]

Comment: What are you trying to show us with the screenshot? We don't know what the original image is/looks like.

Comment: @phuzi actual image has been updated in question. please have a look.

Comment: Looks like the `modalImageFullscreen` component is either not considering the height of the image or not considering the available space. Perhaps it is just overflowing without scroll bars. We would need to see the relevant image sizing code from the `modalImageFullscreen` component.

Comment: @phuzi this is the the code https://gist.github.com/urdeshten24/9f02023cdac249f0214e8c4c496cbf23